# What is the difference between multiplication and direct sum on homotopy groups of spheres?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, spectral-sequences

In Allen Hatcher's book Algebraic topology he states that factoring out 2-torsion $\pi_{i}(S^{2n})\cong\pi_{i-1}(S^{2n-1})\times\pi_{i}(S^{4n-1})\:\forall n$ but in his book Spectral Sequences in Algebraic Topology he has $\pi_{i}(S^{n})\cong\pi_{i-1}(S^{n-1})\bigoplus\pi_{i}(S^{2n-1})\:\forall n$ even. Am I correct in assuming these are the same or am I totally missing something?

Answer (score 6):

Finite direct sums and finite direct products are the same thing on groups. The homotopy theory part has nothing to do with it. (*Infinite* direct sums and products are different, though, so be careful about this.)

Comment: The difference is this: An infinite sum of groups has elements with only finitely many coordinates non-zero. An infinite product does not have this limitation on its elements (the real, formal difference is category-theoretical, but for groups, this is what the difference manifests as)

Answer (score 4):

The higher homotopy groups are all abelian, so for finite indices you have the canonical isomorphism:

$$
\prod^{n}_{i=1}A_{i}=\bigoplus^{n}_{i=1}A_{i}
$$
by mapping $(a_{1}\cdots a_{n})$ to $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}$.

Comment: Abelianness is unnecessary here. (The direct sum still makes sense for nonabelian groups, it just isn't the coproduct anymore. Instead it's the "commutative coproduct.")

Comment: Yes, thanks for the reminder. I am only aware of direct sum as the coproduct. But I think you mean "non-commutative coproduct" right?

Comment: No, I mean "commutative coproduct." The direct sum of a family of groups $G_i$ is the universal group equipped with a map from all of the $G_i$ all of whose images commute.

Comment: I see. Thanks for explaining. This does appear to be the right generalization.